# I use Lua script to copy mp4 files, but other apps(tiktok) cannot find the video

Tags: java, android, linux, shell, lua

Setelah salinan yang berjaya gagal, sistem video Android tidak dapat mengesan video copy.mp4,
dan juga tidak dapat mencari video copy.mp4 yang akan diterbitkan di TikTok.

```
 local ts = require("ts")
 path1 = "/sdcard/Download/aliyunPZ/1/copy.mp4" 
 path2 = "/sdcard/Download/aliyunPZ/1/1.mp4"
 os.execute("cp " ..path1.. " "..path2)
```

1.mp4 can be detected by tiktok

copy.mp4 cannot be detected by tiktok

I don't know what is wrong?

I checked the permissions of two files (adb):

```
-rw-rw---- root sdcard_rw 6939904 2020-11-13 20:21 1. mp4

-rw-rw---- root sdcard_rw 6939904 2020-11-14 1:54 copy. mp4
```

You can see the effect through the picture

[image]

Comment: [![tiktok (other applications) cannot detect copy.mp4][1]]
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LscQ6.jpg

Comment: path = userPath().."/res/1.mp4"
os.execute("am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE -d file://"..path)

Answer (score -1):

Hello sir change name your copy.mp4 to anything else